# Delimit a single auxiliary file into chunks, and include these at separate places?

Tags: include, external-files

I have a LaTeX file for inclusion, automatically generated by a code-documentation tool, so the fact it’s a single file is non-negotiable.  However, I want to include it not all at once, but some parts in one place, some in another — so I’d like to put some sort of delimiting information into the auxiliary file, perhaps giving labels to specific chunks, and then have a syntax for including the individual chunks as though there.

I’m imagining something the following: an auxiliary file `quotations.tex` looking something like:

```
\begin{chunk}{shakespeare}
  \begin{quote}``To be or not to be?''\end{quote}
\end{chunk}

There might also be other content between the chunks, like this.

\begin{chunk}{pythagoras}
  \[ x^2 + y^2 = z^2 \]
\end{chunk}
```

and then in the main file,

```
[preamble etc.]

Shakespeare wrote:
\includechunk{quotations.tex}{shakespeare}

Pythagoras proved:
\includechunk{quotations.tex}{pythagoras}
```

(In my actual document, the chunks are much longer than this — typically a page or two.)  Is there a good way of doing something like this?  The include file is generated by [coqdoc](http://coq.inria.fr/), if that’s relevant.

Comment: Have a look at the `catchfilebetweentag` package.

Comment: @Martin: wonderful, thankyou — that looks perfect for my purpose!  I clearly need to improve my tex-package google-fu.  If you make that an answer, I’ll accept it.

Comment: Don't worry there are a lot of packages on CTAN which I don't know either. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`catchfilebetweentags`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/catchfilebetweentags) package can be used to read a file into a macro between two tags or other markers. I'm not sure if using a `chunk` environment is a good idea, because the end-marker would then be identical for every chunk, but it might actually work, assuming the package reads to the first occurrence of the end-marker.

Comment: Yes, `catchfilebetweentags`’s ability to use custom delimiters works much better for me than doing it as an environment.  Thanks again; this seems to work just as I’d hoped.

Comment: @Martin: The link you provided for `catchfilebetweentag` does not seem to be working.

Comment: @MartinScharrer can you point to a idiot-proof example for this? I can't find anything that actually explains how to use this package to grab and input the tagged sections.

Comment: Nevermind; got it working with `\CatchFileBetweenTags{\whatever}{filename}{tagname}` `\whatever`

Comment: @AndrewBolster: Actually I just figured out that you can't use `{ }` inside the `\CatchFileBetweenDelims` delimiters, but using docstrip-style tags with `\CatchFileBetweenTags` should work fine.