# '\include' sections of files?

Tags: sectioning, include

Is it possible to include a section of a file?

Context: Literature Reviews for thesis, I write long(ish) notes on each paper/article/whatever, but generally have a 'bird's eye view' summary. I'd like to generate a report that just contains these summaries from each individual review file.

If there's a better way to lay this out, I would like to hear those too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could simply put all all review sections in own files which are inserted using `\input` ([not `\include`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include)) in your normal document and also in the extra report. This might seem to be a little extra work, but IMHO is the most straight-forward way to do it.

You could also mark the sections in questions using special tags and then extract them as shown in [Delimit a single auxiliary file into chunks, and include these at separate places?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25779/delimit-a-single-auxiliary-file-into-chunks-and-include-these-at-separate-place/25782#25782), but personally I find this overly complicated in this case where it is only one section per chapter and not multiple chunks.

Comment: +1 for pointing out \input to me. I think that for my purposes and plans for development, the catchfilebetweentags is worth trying for now. Will mark as answered after a customary 24hr wait.